# PC in VMWARE can ping Host computer but host computer can't ping the VMWARE machine

Tags: web-server

I'm creating PFsense lab with this diagram 
[image]

The Webserver can ping the outside host (PC3) but the PC3 can't ping the webserver.
The firewall i'm using is PFSense.

I have disabled all Window Firewall features on both PCs and on my router. 
I have also added a rule to pass all traffic through the Firewall.

Comment: What IP are you using to ping the web server? Does the ICMP traffic is allowed across the firewall?

Comment: IP i'm use to ping Webserver is 172.16.1.3.I'm created  rules so all traffic can pass firewall 1 (any-any).Main purpose of me is public webserver to internet..thank y jorel

Answer (score 1):

172.16.1.3 is a private IP address. You cant ping a private IP over the internet. In order to route to the IP address and ping that address, the IP should be a public IP.  You can read more about it over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

You can use port forwarding and then try to ping the server over the public IP.

Comment: i'm NAT in pfsense with Redirected target ip is 172.16.1.3 with port 80.How i can get the public IP?  Is IP outside firewall 1 or IP outside my router??